# How do I setup WebDav server and XDBC Server in single directory in MarkLogic8

Tags: marklogic, webdav, marklogic-8

I have MarkLogic8 server installed on my DEV box. How can I start WebDav server and XDBC Server in same directory in MarkLogic8. So I can upload my XQuery files from WebDav and execute from XDBC server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to the App Servers section in the Admin ui once you have created your database, and create two servers linked to the same database.

The WebDAV one has only one database option. The XDBC has both a modules and a documents database option. Specify your database as modules database in the XDBC server to be able to execute and invoke code that you uploaded with WebDAV.

Note: there are other, better ways to get code deployed, like ml-gradle and Roxy. Using WebDAV will make it harder to apply appropriate document permissions to grant users execute access for instance.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have uploaded test.xqy with above configuration still getting 404 not found error.

Comment: You will need to provide more detail about how the servers are configured. Also, details about what user you use to upload and to execute helps. You can edit the question to insert extra details..

Comment: it takes some time to reflect changes I think due to windows-7 OS, it worked. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good information provided by @grtjn, you'll need to change one setting for WebDAV to be happy. On the database that you want to point WebDAV to, change the "directory creation" setting from manual (the default) to automatic. Without that, WebDAV is unable to see the directories.

I also second @grtjn's recommendation to use [ml-gradle](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle) or [Roxy](https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy) instead of WebDAV.